# Extending the integral of a bounded measurable function from a measurable set $E$ to the whole of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $g(x)$ be a bounded measurable function such that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E g(nx)dx = 0$$ for any measurable set $E$ with finite measure. Given $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, do we have $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int _{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(nx)dx = 0?$$

My approach is to partition $\mathbb{R}$ into a countable collection of intervals, say, $E_i=[i, i+1]$, and we consider the integral $$\int_{E_i} f(x)g(nx) dx.$$
Since $g$ is bounded, we can find $M_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$-M_nf(x) \leq f(x)g(nx) \leq M_nf(x)$$ and so the integral will be bounded above by $$M_n\int_{E_i}f(x)dx,$$
which is finite. By hypothesis, we have that $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E_i} g(nx)dx = 0$$ and so the sequence of upper bounds $\{M_n\}$ converges to zero as well. Hence $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int _{E_i} f(x)g(nx)dx = 0.$$
Could we then conclude that $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int _{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(nx)dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \int _{E_i} f(x)g(nx)dx = \sum_{i=1} ^\infty \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int _{E_i} f(x)g(nx)dx = 0?$$

I can't properly justify why I could switch the summation and limit and I'm not very good at manipulating the arbitrary integral of a product of functions, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: A series is an integral with respect to a counting measure, and so you can generalise the hypothesis of dominated convergence to series. I think you are allowed to switch the signs, but you will still probably need to justify this. This is the point where the assumption $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ becomes useful. If you need help or don't find the statement of the result I mention, tell me

Comment: @Evaristo Alright I will try to look it up and strengthen my argument. Does the buildup of the proof prior to the switching part make sense?

Comment: Haven't seen anything bad with it

Comment: Maybe more care with the fact $f$ can take negative values. The bound you take should be $-M_n |f(x)|\leq f(x)g(nx)\leq M_n|f(x)|$ to account for this. Otherwise, the argument is solid

Comment: @Evaristo I tried to apply DCT as you mentioned, by viewing the summation as an integral. The functions $$|\int _{E_i} f(x)g(nx)dx|$$ are bounded above by $$\int _{E_i}M'|f(x)|dx$$ where $M'$ is the supremum of $\{M_n\}$, and $\int _{E_i}M'|f(x)|dx$ belongs to $L^1$. Then we can invoke DCT. Would this suffice? Or is there something about $f$ being in $L^1$ that I overlooked?

Comment: Just realised that the problem is not switching limit and sum, that is done without problem. The real problem is switching sum and integral. Check this link for the argument you need to develop http://mathonline.wikidot.com/lebesgue-s-dominated-convergence-theorem-for-series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prove this lemma:

Let $a_{m,n}$ be a real-valued sequence on $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Suppose that $|a_{m,n}|\leq r_m$ for all $m$ and $n$,

that $\displaystyle \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}r_m$ converges,

and that for each $m$ we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{m,n}=s_m\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Then** obviously $\displaystyle\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}s_m$ converges,

and for each $n$ we find that $\displaystyle\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{m,n}$ converges,

and also $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{m,n}$ exists and is equal to $\displaystyle\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}s_m$.

$\\$

Because $f$ is in $L_1(\mathbb{R})\supset L_1[j,j+1]$

and $|g(x)|<M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,

we have

$\displaystyle\bigg|\int_{[j,j+1]}f(x)g(nx)\,\text{d}x\bigg|$

$\leq M\displaystyle\int_{[j,j+1]}|f(x)|\,\text{d}x$.

Also, from $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ itself,

it follows that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \int_{[j,j+1]}|f(x)|\,\text{d}x$ converges.

Obviously then $\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty M\int_{[j,j+1]}|f(x)|\,\text{d}x$ converges.

Therefore,

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty\int_{[j,j+1]}f(x)g(nx)\,\text{d}x$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[j,j+1]}f(x)g(nx)\,\text{d}x$

$=0$.